# Change data for an ASP.NET MVC view based on debug/release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, faker

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app using .NET Framework 4.6.1 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I'm planning to use the Faker.Data library (https://github.com/FermJacob/Faker.Data) to produce fake data for debug mode in development; it might be some time before I have real data which will reside in SQL Server.

I need to have the views use this fake data in debug mode. Is it possible to use something like this in the `cshtml` view file to switch the data?

```
#if DEBUG
    // Point to fake data for this view
#else
    // Point to release data for this view
#endif
```

The view currently has this statement at the top to provide a strongly-typed model:

```
@model MyProject.DAL.Customer
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your choice of datasource should go in the controller and be sent to the view.  The view shouldn't have any code in it to select the datasource.

Comment: Thanks, @Ilnetd. Dang, was afraid you'd say that. Was hoping I could avoid that, but in MVC, what you described is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor usualy doesn't work in razor correctly, you can put that code like this

```
@{
#if DEBUG
    // Point to fake data for this view
#else
    // Point to release data for this view
#endif
}
```

But this code doesn't return expected result.
you can define an extention method for `HtmlHelper` class like this:

```
public static bool IsDebugMode(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
   #if DEBUG
       return true;
   #else
      return false;
   #endif
}
```

At the end you can call that extention method in razor syntax like this one:

```
@if(Html.IsDebugMode()){}
```

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` is available in your views. However, your view should be receiving a View Model from the controller, as opposed to the data/datasource being selected in the View

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` instead of `#if DEBUG` as it may cause to encounter some kind of compile errors. For more information have a look at [If you're using “#IF DEBUG”, you're doing it wrong](http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2011/11/24/if-you-re-using-if-debug-you-re-doing-it-wrong/). Hope this helps...